# Show div when more than six list items exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to show a parent search div on click of div element or on page load if list items are more than six. I try with `siblings()` and `siblings().closest()` but not working.

Please see the code and codepen live code link below.

Code :https://codepen.io/codepat007/pen/BaKvvoE

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wrap', function() {

  if ($(this).find('.searchresult ul li').length > 6) {
    $(this).siblings().closest('.SearchWrap').show();
  }

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 30%
}

.SearchWrap {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>123</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <p>456</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>789</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <div class="nodata">no data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your use of "parent" implies the parent of the clicked element. It's irrelevant that it's the parent of a search input. The contents of the shown element don't matter.

Comment: And you really shouldn't move the target by changing your parameters after answers have been posted.

Comment: Do you really want this to run  only when the document has been clicked, or was that the way you chose to make sure the function ran and hid, or showed, the relevant elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using CSS class-names to handle the showing, or hiding, of the various elements on the page, this is often more reliable and extensible than manipulating the inline `style` attribute of individual elements, especially if you need to put those elements back into their default state after manipulating multiple properties.

Ideally the elements should be hidden, and therefore the class should be added, with JavaScript so that the elements are visible in the absence of JavaScript being permitted to run on the page. Which is why I've also added the line

```
$('.SearchWrap').addClass('hidden');
```

to the JavaScript, below. That said, one approach is below:

```
// causes the enclosed functionality to execute only once the
// document is ready, and the content loaded:
$(document).ready(function() {

  // using jQuery to find the '.SearchWrap' elements
  // and add the 'hidden' class-name to them in order
  // hide them on page-load:
  $('.SearchWrap').addClass('hidden');

  // binding the anonymous function of the on() method as the
  // event-handler for the 'click' event when that event
  // originates from, or from within, an element with the
  // class-name of 'wrap':
  $(document).on('click', '.wrap', function() {

    // here 'this' (and $(this)) refer to the .wrap
    // element upon, or within, which the 'click' orginated:
    $(this)

      // from the .wrap' element we find the '.SearchWrap'
      // descendant(s) and we call the toggleClass() method:

      .find('.SearchWrap')
      // within the toggleClass() method-call we pass a
      // class-name ('hidden') and an assessment:
      .toggleClass('hidden',
      
        // if this assessment evaluates to true then
        // the class-name is added, if it evaluates
        // to false it is removed or not-added. The
        // assessment here is to find the elements
        // within the current .wrap element that match
        // the CSS selector, and tests that the length
        // is less than 6; in this way if the length
        // is less than 6 (and evaluates to true) the
        // 'hidden' class-name is applied to .SearchWrap
        // otherwise, if the element is 6 or more the
        // assessment evaluates to false, and the
        // 'hidden' class-name is removed or not-added,
        // so .SearchWrap remains visible or becomes
        // visible:
        $(this).find('.searchresult li').length < 6
      );
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.SearchWrap').addClass('hidden');
  $(document).on('click', '.wrap', function() {
    $(this).find('.SearchWrap').toggleClass('hidden',
      $(this).find('.searchresult li').length < 6
    );
  });
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.SearchWrap {
  display: initial;
}

.SearchWrap.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>123</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <p>456</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>789</p>
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="searchresult">
    <div class="nodata">no data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fe8v9myd/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems with your DOM traversal. Let's capture the clicked paragraph for later reference and use the `siblings()` function with a class modifier.

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrap p', function() {
  const paragraph = $(this);

  if (paragraph.siblings('.searchresult').find('ul li').length > 6) {
    paragraph.siblings('.SearchWrap').show();
  }
});
```